# Unable to understand algorithm for Longest Increasing Sub-sequence

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have been through many online resources to understand how the problem has the optimal sub-structure, but all in vain, I am unable to comprehend how the solution is obtained by solving smaller sub-problems in this case.

I would be thankful if any explanation helps in understanding the solution.

so far, I understand the optimal sub-structure property as follows:

Example Factorial:

So for a factorial of 40 ,fact(40), we can achieve the solution by calculating fact(39)*40, and so on for 39,38....2 ans as we know that fact(2) is 2 we can build it up from 2 to 40 in the same way.

**But I am not able to relate in terms of LIS, please help**

A full explanation of the solution would be nice, excluding the overlapping subproblems issue, as that can be handled later on.

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, Hiresh - are you confusing recursion and LIS, by chance?  Typically, the algorithm for LIS (which may be recursive) involves a sequence as an input.  (typically for sorting, to determine O).  The factorial example given is recursion.

Comment: Hi John, although the example is recursive, I think has a optimal substructure property, as the small problems are used to build up the final problem, pls correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Please see the answer below - the issue with N!, and its optimal substructure is that the very definition of N! (and the sequence derived) yields an LIS of length N. Again, a different question, for a different purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before considering optimal substructure, you need to decide what are subproblems in the case of LIS. Let's use this definition:

> In an array `a[N]` of length `N` a subproblem `LIS[k]` is to find the length of a longest increasing subsequence from the initial index, which ends precisely at the element `a[k]`.

It is important to understand the difference here: `LIS[k]` is *not* a solution to LIS on the first `k` elements; that would be `Max(LIS[i])` for all `i`s up to `k`. It is the length of the longest increasing subsequence that ends at the particular element.

With this definition in hand, it is easy to construct a solution to LIS:

- For each `i` up to `N`:
- Set `LIS[i]` to 1 (in the worst case, a number is a subsequence of one)
- Search `LIS[j]` from the initial element up to `i-1`, inclusive, for `j`s such that `a[i] > a[j]`, and `LIS[j]+1 > LIS[i]`.

It is easy to see that the above algorithm constructs a solution to `LIS[i]` given solutions to subproblems `LIS[j]` for all `j`s below `i` in O(i). Since we can construct a solution to a `k` problem from solutions to `k-1` sub-problems, the problem has optimal substructure.

**Note:** The above can be further optimized by using binary search. The reasoning about subproblem and optimal substructure remains the same, though.

Comment: I would like to request @dasblinkenlight to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43236912/how-does-finding-a-longest-increasing-subsequence-that-ends-with-a-particular-el](answer this, this will finally solve the issue for me)

Answer (score 1):

LIS for the sequence (problem) can be solved by using LIS for the smaller sequences (sub-problem)and that's why it is known to have the optimal sub-structure.

Let me try to explain how this works with the example. Let's take a random sequence of 10 numbers:

[21, 24, 13, 48, -3, 41, 36, 8, -10, 22]

We will use smaller problems (smaller sequence) to solve this problem. The definition of the subproblem is this case is 'What is the longest increasing sequence of numbers that ends at a given element?'

It is important to understand that this subproblem is NOT the same as LIS- the subproblem has a stricter definition that the original problem (LIS doesn't need to end at the last element).

For readability purposes, I'll call the 'longest increasing subsequence that ends at given element': LIS*.

The relationship between LIS* and LIS is that LIS takes `Max` of LIS*

Let's start with just one number.

[21]

What is the longest increasing subsequence that ends at 21? It is simply '21'. Therefore the length of our sequence is 1.

Sequence: [21]
LIS*: 1
LIS:  1

Now, for the second element (24), according to the definition, we need to use the solution for the problem we already solved. We will use LIS for the first element, check whether second element is bigger (`a[i] > a[j`) and whether `LIS[j]+1 > LIS[i]`. The longest increasing sequence that ends at 24 is '21, 24' and has the length of 2.

Sequence: [21, 24]
LIS*: 2
LIS:  2

Let's take 3rd element (13). What is the longest increasing subsequence that ends at 13? Well, 13 is smaller than 21 and smaller than 24 so the condition `a[i] > a[j]` is not fulfilled for any of the previous elements.The longest increasing subsequence that ends at 13 is therefore just '13' and has the length of 1. LIS for sequence 21,24,13 is still 2.

Sequence: [21, 24, 13]
LIS*: 1
LIS:  2

Let's look at 4th element (48). We know that the solution for the 3-length sequence was 2. We can find previous element (24) that fulfils criteria `a[i] > a[j]` and `LIS[j]+1 > LIS[i]`. We know that solution for the previous element (smaller problem) was 2, therefore the solution here will be 2+1=3.

Sequence: [21, 24, 13, 48]
LIS*: 3 
LIS:  3

We repeat the logic for all subsequent elements.

Sequence: [21, 24, 13, 48, -3, 41, 36, 8, -10, 22]
LIS*:            1    2    1    3    1    3    3    2    1    3
LIS:             1    2    2    3    3    3    3    3    3    3

As you can see, the solution to the original problem (long sequence) can be obtained by looking at sub-problem (smaller sequences) and therefore this problem is known to have the optimal sub-structure.