# How does finding a Longest Increasing Subsequence that ends with a particular element leads to the solution of finding LIS

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I have understood that to find the solution of LIS problem, we need to find a LIS for every subsequence starting from initial element of the array to the each element that ends with a particular element(the last element), but I am not able to understand how would that help in finally finding a LIS of a given unsorted array, I also understand that this leads to an optimal substructure property and then can be solved, but as mentioned, I dont see how finding LIS(j) that ends with arr[j] will help us.

thanks.

Comment: Simply because all you have to do from that point is to search the `j` with the longest LIS(j).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this sequence as an example:

```
a[]   : 10 20  1  2  5 30  6  8 50  5  7
```

It produces the following sequence of `LIS[i]`:

```
a[]   : 10 20  1  2  5 30  6  8 50  5  7
LIS[] :  1  2  1  2  3  4  4  5  6  3  4
```

Given this sequence, you can immediately find the length of the result, and its last element: the length is 6, and the last element is 50.

Now you can unfold the rest of the sequence, starting from the back: looking for `LIS` of `5` (one less than that of element `50`) such that the number is less than `50` yields 8. Looking back further for `4` gives you `6` (there is no tie, because `30` is above `8`). Next comes `5` with `LIS` of `3`, and then a `2` with `LIS` of `2`. Note that there is no tie again, even though `20` has the same `LIS`. This is because `20` is above `5`. Finally, we find `1` with `LIS` of `1`, completing the sequence:

```
50  8  6  5  2  1
```

Reversing this produces the longest increasing subsequence:

```
1 2 5 6 8 50
```

This is a common trick: given a table with the value of the function that you are maximizing (i.e. the length) you can produce the answer that yields this function (i.e. the sequence itself) by back-tracking the steps of the algorithm to the initial element.

Comment: Might be stupid question but I am new to dynamic programming, how is LIS[] indexation created?